# IN REACT, how can I request API before rendered

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks

**My Application: Laravel(API SERVER) + React(Frontend)**

What I want to do is restrict the access to routes of `App` if the user is not authenticated.

```
function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = setState({isSignedIn: false});
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin/*" element={ userInfo.isSignedIn? <Admin />: <Navigate replace to="/home/sign-in"/> } />
      <Route path="/home/*" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

To do that, auth API should be requested before App rendered.

My first try was like...

```
function App() {
  const requestUserInfo = async() => {
    const result = await axios.get("/auth");
    return result.data;
  }
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = setState(requestUserInfo);
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/admin/*" element={ userInfo.isSignedIn? <Admin />: <Navigate replace to="/home/sign-in"/> } />
      <Route path="/home/*" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

However I realized initial state cannot be async.
Also I tried axios in useEffect(), but I think it forces too many rerendering.

So Here Is My Question: **What is the most common way to get auth info by API?**